# Store multiple form fields as JSON string

Tags: component, jform

I'm trying to store multiple field values in a JSON string in my component but I'm not quite sure how to go about it. I've done some research and it seems that using the `load` and `bind` `JTable` methods are the way to go but I don't know how to render the fields on my form and vice versa.

Any tips or advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it either in your Table class or Model class:

```
// Convert a JSON field to an array
$registry = new JRegistry;
$registry->loadString($item->jsonfield);
$item->jsonfield = $registry->toArray();
```

See [the reference](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/administrator/components/com_content/models/article.php#L257)

And vice versa:

```
// Convert an array field to a JSON
if (isset($data['jsonfield']) && is_array($data['jsonfield']))
{
    $registry = new JRegistry;
    $registry->loadArray($data['jsonfield']);
    $data['jsonfield'] = (string) $registry;
}
```

See [the reference](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/administrator/components/com_content/models/article.php#L445)