# Accessing Form fields in the Model

Tags: joomla-3.x, jform

I was able to get and set values of my custom form fields by using $form->getValue and $form->setValue in my previous issue here:

[How to access / modify custom form fields values](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5604/how-to-access-modify-custom-form-fields-values)

However, I am only able to use setValue and getValue in the function where the form was initialized. How do I make it such when I call the save function, I can access the form together with the custom fields I added during my loadForm() function?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the form values by storing the code below to a variable:

```
JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('jform', array(), 'array');
```